# Construct list with fixed window length from a known list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a simple list as

```
list = Range[100]
```

and the output is

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, \
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, \
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, \
54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, \
71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, \
88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100}
```

assuming a var as window length as

```
wlen = 10
```

how to get a new list from the upper one with `Map` or `MoivingMap`, and the new list shall be like this

```
result = {{1}, {1, 2},{1, 2, 3}, ... ,
         {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
         {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11} , ... ,
         {90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99},
         {91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try Subsets[list,wlen]   ?

Comment: Subsets[list,wlen] does not give the result list but `SystemException[MemoryAllocationFailure]`;)

Comment: I raise the question for doing backtesting on stock prices list, where backtesting function could be applied on the sub-list with fixed length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `MovingMap`, you can pad your array with some symbol and then substitute it by `Nothing`.

```
wlen = 10;
list = Range[100];
paddedArray = Join[ ConstantArray[None, wlen - 1],  list];
movingMapResult = MovingMap[Sequence, paddedArray, wlen - 1];
movingMapResult /. None -> Nothing
```

One-line version:

```
MovingMap[Sequence, ArrayPad[list, {wlen-1, 0}, None], wlen-1] /. None->Nothing
```

Using `MovingMap` Padding option:

```
MovingMap[Sequence, list, wlen-1, {Automatic, None}] /. None->Nothing
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks! :)

Comment: how to reach your level on `MMA` is another question ;)

Answer (score 6):

No need for anything fancy like `MovingMap[]`:

```
list = Range[100]; wlen = 10;
Partition[list, wlen, 1, -1, {}]
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Thanks! :)

Comment: The upper `Partition` is beyond my understanding..;)

Comment: sorry, I could only accept one answer. Thanks for your helping !

Comment: (+1) also: `Partition[list, UpTo @ wlen, 1, -1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Range[If[NonNegative[# - wlen], # - wlen-1, 1], #] & /@ list
```

Comment: Good, but If `list` is changed the other, the code shall be modified.

Comment: @Jerry The edit is your after?

Comment: not exactly, `Range[If[NonNegative[#-wlen],#-wlen-1,1],#]&/@(Reverse@Range[100])` should begin with {100},{100,99}...

Comment: sorry, I could only accept one answer. Thanks for your helping !

Comment: You are welcome,be my guest. :)

Comment: you can also use `Table[If[i >= 10, Range[i - 9, i], Range[i]], {i, 100}]`

Comment: @AliHashmi Thanks for your attention to an answer without vote in a post without vote. :^)

Comment: @yode you got yours now :)

Comment: @AliHashmi Thanks,just a joke. :)

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work

```
list = Range[10];
wlen = 5;
consecutiveQ = Most[#] == Rest[#] - 1 &;
Select[Drop[Subsets[list, wlen], 1], consecutiveQ]
```

Comment: Subsets causes `SystemException[MemoryAllocationFailure]` here either.

Comment: I made an edit for a smaller set. Is this the result you should get?

Comment: It works for Range[20] and wlen=10.... but for Range[100] the result is very big

Comment: yes, but if `list`changed to  `Reverse@Range[10]`, the code is limited.